# How to convert files from mbox format to PST?

Tags: windows, email, conversion

I'm using readpst to convert a PST file from Outlook into text files which can be parsed in Linux. I want to select a subset of these messages, and make a new PST out of them so that they can be read in Outlook on Windows. Is there a way to do this in Linux?